# how to scroll a footer automatically to focus a particular highlighted div in ionic3

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, ionic3

i am trying to scroll my ionic3 footer automatically to the focused div like,  iam having 9 menus in my home page and those 9 menus icons where showing in my footer, if i clicked an icon in footer then it goes to that particular page, after going into that page my footer has to scroll upto to that particular page icon, but iam not getting that, please sought out of this problem

### below is my current behaviour image

[image]

### expected behaviourimage

[image]

like the last image when i goes to that flights page, my footer has to scroll upto that icon , but now it is not happening

### here is my code

```
    <ion-footer>
    <div style="display:inline-flex;border-top: 1px solid #b3b3b3;overflow-x:auto;" class="scroll-content" #footerCont (ionScroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
        <div class="col" [navPush]="homePage" [ngStyle]="pageName == 'homePage' && {'color': themePrimaryColor}">
            <ion-icon name="footer-home"></ion-icon>
            <p>Home</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col" [navPush]="itineraryPage" [ngStyle]="pageName == 'itineraryPage' && {'color': themePrimaryColor}">
            <ion-icon name="footer-itinerary"></ion-icon>
            <p>itinerary</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col " [navPush]="chatPage" [ngStyle]="pageName == 'chatPage' && {'color': themePrimaryColor}">
            <ion-icon  name="footer-chat-bubble-two"></ion-icon>
            <p>chat</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col"  [ngStyle]="pageName == 'aboutPage' && {'color': themePrimaryColor}">
            <ion-icon  name="footer-about"></ion-icon>
            <p>About</p>
        </div>
       ::
       :://all footer icons
       ::
        <div class="col"  [ngStyle]="pageName == 'flghtsPage' && {'color': themePrimaryColor}">
            <ion-icon  name="footer-flights"></ion-icon>
            <p>flights</p>
        </div>
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```